# data-table hide/ show column

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html-table, datatables

I am using data-tables for some beautiful features,here i am using data-tables to fix columns of my table

**Table structure**

- I am making my table with JSON data which is pure dynamic using Java-Script
- Above my table i have a drop-down field which user selects then clicks go and i am showing only that columns which user is selecting
- when user selects 1 or two columns then columns of `tbody` and `thead are breaking`
- When i am removing fixedColumn then it is working fine but i need to implement fixedColumn
- The columns i have fixed are also visible twice when i selects dropdowns and press go

**Working Code**

```js
function format(number, decimals = 2, locale = 'en-in') {
  const fixed = parseInt(number).toFixed(decimals);
  const [int, dec] = fixed.split('.')
  const intFormatted = (+int).toLocaleString(locale)
  return intFormatted + (dec ? '.' + dec : '');
}

var data = [{
  "billdate": "2018-08-04",
  "outlet": "JAYANAGAR",
  "gross": 490465,
  "discount": 839,
  "GST": 28465,
  "amount": 518212
}, {
  "billdate": "2018-08-04",
  "outlet": "MALLESHWARAM",
  "gross": 99212,
  "discount": 0,
  "GST": 5567,
  "amount": 104801
}, {
  "billdate": "2018-08-04",
  "outlet": "KOLAR",
  "gross": 131349,
  "discount": 0,
  "GST": 6676,
  "amount": 138151
}, {
  "billdate": "2018-08-05",
  "outlet": "JAYANAGAR",
  "gross": 594466,
  "discount": 591,
  "GST": 34374,
  "amount": 628358
}, {
  "billdate": "2018-08-05",
  "outlet": "MALLESHWARAM",
  "gross": 109029,
  "discount": 0,
  "GST": 6062,
  "amount": 115113
}, {
  "billdate": "2018-08-05",
  "outlet": "KOLAR",
  "gross": 127449,
  "discount": 0,
  "GST": 6511,
  "amount": 134107
}, {
  "billdate": "2018-08-06",
  "outlet": "JAYANAGAR",
  "gross": 167811,
  "discount": 0,
  "GST": 9968,
  "amount": 177866
}, {
  "billdate": "2018-08-06",
  "outlet": "KOLAR",
  "gross": 62796,
  "discount": 0,
  "GST": 3257,
  "amount": 66095
}, {
  "billdate": "2018-08-07",
  "outlet": "JAYANAGAR",
  "gross": 267398,
  "discount": 268,
  "GST": 15898,
  "amount": 283124
}, {
  "billdate": "2018-08-07",
  "outlet": "MALLESHWARAM",
  "gross": 55381,
  "discount": 0,
  "GST": 3383,
  "amount": 58789
}, {
  "billdate": "2018-08-07",
  "outlet": "KOLAR",
  "gross": 64586,
  "discount": 6,
  "GST": 3285,
  "amount": 67886
}, {
  "billdate": "2018-08-08",
  "outlet": "JAYANAGAR",
  "gross": 295544,
  "discount": 246,
  "GST": 17716,
  "amount": 313128
}, {
  "billdate": "2018-08-08",
  "outlet": "MALLESHWARAM",
  "gross": 56453,
  "discount": 0,
  "GST": 3462,
  "amount": 59939
}, {
  "billdate": "2018-08-08",
  "outlet": "KOLAR",
  "gross": 65159,
  "discount": 0,
  "GST": 3381,
  "amount": 68558
}, {
  "billdate": "2018-08-09",
  "outlet": "JAYANAGAR",
  "gross": 303778,
  "discount": 201,
  "GST": 18115,
  "amount": 321797
}, {
  "billdate": "2018-08-09",
  "outlet": "MALLESHWARAM",
  "gross": 60795,
  "discount": 0,
  "GST": 3620,
  "amount": 64431
}, {
  "billdate": "2018-08-09",
  "outlet": "KOLAR",
  "gross": 54495,
  "discount": 0,
  "GST": 2841,
  "amount": 57352
}, {
  "billdate": "2018-08-10",
  "outlet": "JAYANAGAR",
  "gross": 305223,
  "discount": 53,
  "GST": 18287,
  "amount": 323556
}, {
  "billdate": "2018-08-10",
  "outlet": "MALLESHWARAM",
  "gross": 55584,
  "discount": 36,
  "GST": 3207,
  "amount": 58772
}, {
  "billdate": "2018-08-10",
  "outlet": "KOLAR",
  "gross": 41584,
  "discount": 0,
  "GST": 2128,
  "amount": 43722
}, {
  "billdate": "2018-08-11",
  "outlet": "JAYANAGAR",
  "gross": 439024,
  "discount": 177,
  "GST": 25148,
  "amount": 464127
}, {
  "billdate": "2018-08-11",
  "outlet": "MALLESHWARAM",
  "gross": 88009,
  "discount": 0,
  "GST": 5090,
  "amount": 93110
}, {
  "billdate": "2018-08-11",
  "outlet": "KOLAR",
  "gross": 59188,
  "discount": 0,
  "GST": 3156,
  "amount": 62213
}, {
  "billdate": "2018-08-12",
  "outlet": "JAYANAGAR",
  "gross": 593776,
  "discount": 809,
  "GST": 33689,
  "amount": 626772
}, {
  "billdate": "2018-08-12",
  "outlet": "MALLESHWARAM",
  "gross": 119723,
  "discount": 45,
  "GST": 7245,
  "amount": 126933
}, {
  "billdate": "2018-08-12",
  "outlet": "KOLAR",
  "gross": 59926,
  "discount": 0,
  "GST": 3170,
  "amount": 63119
}, {
  "billdate": "2018-08-13",
  "outlet": "JAYANAGAR",
  "gross": 157580,
  "discount": 340,
  "GST": 10053,
  "amount": 167391
}, {
  "billdate": "2018-08-13",
  "outlet": "KOLAR",
  "gross": 25730,
  "discount": 0,
  "GST": 1368,
  "amount": 27110
}, {
  "billdate": "2018-08-14",
  "outlet": "JAYANAGAR",
  "gross": 260106,
  "discount": 298,
  "GST": 15181,
  "amount": 275115
}, {
  "billdate": "2018-08-14",
  "outlet": "MALLESHWARAM",
  "gross": 55145,
  "discount": 19,
  "GST": 3480,
  "amount": 58633
}, {
  "billdate": "2018-08-14",
  "outlet": "KOLAR",
  "gross": 36664,
  "discount": 0,
  "GST": 1916,
  "amount": 37920
}, {
  "billdate": "2018-08-15",
  "outlet": "JAYANAGAR",
  "gross": 478163,
  "discount": 688,
  "GST": 27138,
  "amount": 504753
}, {
  "billdate": "2018-08-15",
  "outlet": "MALLESHWARAM",
  "gross": 98179,
  "discount": 0,
  "GST": 5661,
  "amount": 103855
}, {
  "billdate": "2018-08-15",
  "outlet": "KOLAR",
  "gross": 98536,
  "discount": 0,
  "GST": 4964,
  "amount": 103519
}, {
  "billdate": "2018-08-16",
  "outlet": "JAYANAGAR",
  "gross": 277139,
  "discount": 594,
  "GST": 16406,
  "amount": 293049
}, {
  "billdate": "2018-08-16",
  "outlet": "MALLESHWARAM",
  "gross": 52828,
  "discount": 0,
  "GST": 3227,
  "amount": 56071
}, {
  "billdate": "2018-08-16",
  "outlet": "KOLAR",
  "gross": 53312,
  "discount": 0,
  "GST": 2730,
  "amount": 56061
}, {
  "billdate": "2018-08-17",
  "outlet": "JAYANAGAR",
  "gross": 329539,
  "discount": 91,
  "GST": 19882,
  "amount": 349456
}, {
  "billdate": "2018-08-17",
  "outlet": "MALLESHWARAM",
  "gross": 62946,
  "discount": 0,
  "GST": 3659,
  "amount": 66624
}, {
  "billdate": "2018-08-17",
  "outlet": "KOLAR",
  "gross": 69126,
  "discount": 0,
  "GST": 3501,
  "amount": 72643
}, {
  "billdate": "2018-08-18",
  "outlet": "JAYANAGAR",
  "gross": 443783,
  "discount": 724,
  "GST": 25712,
  "amount": 468771
}, {
  "billdate": "2018-08-18",
  "outlet": "MALLESHWARAM",
  "gross": 95622,
  "discount": 0,
  "GST": 5507,
  "amount": 101151
}, {
  "billdate": "2018-08-18",
  "outlet": "KOLAR",
  "gross": 107235,
  "discount": 0,
  "GST": 5683,
  "amount": 112950
}, {
  "billdate": "2018-08-19",
  "outlet": "JAYANAGAR",
  "gross": 517922,
  "discount": 181,
  "GST": 28972,
  "amount": 546845
}, {
  "billdate": "2018-08-19",
  "outlet": "MALLESHWARAM",
  "gross": 96821,
  "discount": 0,
  "GST": 5490,
  "amount": 102334
}, {
  "billdate": "2018-08-19",
  "outlet": "KOLAR",
  "gross": 94158,
  "discount": 0,
  "GST": 4909,
  "amount": 99089
}, {
  "billdate": "2018-08-20",
  "outlet": "JAYANAGAR",
  "gross": 156224,
  "discount": 35,
  "GST": 9423,
  "amount": 165700
}, {
  "billdate": "2018-08-20",
  "outlet": "KOLAR",
  "gross": 45547,
  "discount": 0,
  "GST": 2347,
  "amount": 47905
}, {
  "billdate": "2018-08-21",
  "outlet": "JAYANAGAR",
  "gross": 289268,
  "discount": 214,
  "GST": 17613,
  "amount": 306776
}, {
  "billdate": "2018-08-21",
  "outlet": "MALLESHWARAM",
  "gross": 57684,
  "discount": 0,
  "GST": 3374,
  "amount": 61080
}, {
  "billdate": "2018-08-21",
  "outlet": "KOLAR",
  "gross": 57725,
  "discount": 0,
  "GST": 2950,
  "amount": 60682
}, {
  "billdate": "2018-08-22",
  "outlet": "JAYANAGAR",
  "gross": 395657,
  "discount": 159,
  "GST": 22808,
  "amount": 418418
}, {
  "billdate": "2018-08-22",
  "outlet": "MALLESHWARAM",
  "gross": 82752,
  "discount": 0,
  "GST": 4618,
  "amount": 87390
}, {
  "billdate": "2018-08-22",
  "outlet": "KOLAR",
  "gross": 74048,
  "discount": 0,
  "GST": 3953,
  "amount": 77922
}, {
  "billdate": "2018-08-23",
  "outlet": "JAYANAGAR",
  "gross": 302731,
  "discount": 1124,
  "GST": 17774,
  "amount": 319472
}, {
  "billdate": "2018-08-23",
  "outlet": "MALLESHWARAM",
  "gross": 63555,
  "discount": 0,
  "GST": 3565,
  "amount": 67142
}, {
  "billdate": "2018-08-23",
  "outlet": "KOLAR",
  "gross": 53637,
  "discount": 0,
  "GST": 2860,
  "amount": 56506
}, {
  "billdate": "2018-08-24",
  "outlet": "JAYANAGAR",
  "gross": 284354,
  "discount": 774,
  "GST": 16423,
  "amount": 300111
}, {
  "billdate": "2018-08-24",
  "outlet": "MALLESHWARAM",
  "gross": 48130,
  "discount": 0,
  "GST": 2857,
  "amount": 50997
}, {
  "billdate": "2018-08-24",
  "outlet": "KOLAR",
  "gross": 55040,
  "discount": 0,
  "GST": 2871,
  "amount": 57926
}]




let formatData = function(data) {
  let billdates = [];
  let outlets = [];
  data.forEach(element => {
    if (billdates.indexOf(element.billdate) == -1) {
      billdates.push(element.billdate);
    }
    if (outlets.indexOf(element.outlet) == -1) {
      outlets.push(element.outlet);
    }
  });
  return {
    data: data,
    billdates: billdates,
    outlets: outlets,

  };
};

let renderTable = function(data) {
  billdates = data.billdates;
  outlets = data.outlets;
  data = data.data;
  let tbl = document.getElementById("dailySales");
  let table = document.createElement("table");
  let thead = document.createElement("thead");
  let headerRow = document.createElement("tr");
  let th = document.createElement("th");
  th.innerHTML = "BillDate";
  th.classList.add("text-center");
  headerRow.appendChild(th);
  let grandTotal = 0;
  let grandGross = 0;
  let grandDiscount = 0;
  let grandGst = 0;
  let outletWiseTotal = {};
  let outletWiseGross = {};
  let outletWiseDiscount = {};
  let outletWiseGst = {};
  th = document.createElement("th");
  th.colSpan = 4;
  th.innerHTML = "Total";
  th.classList.add("text-center");
  headerRow.appendChild(th);
  outlets.forEach(element => {

    th = document.createElement("th");
    th.colSpan = 4;
    th.innerHTML = element;
    th.classList.add("text-center");
    headerRow.appendChild(th);

    outletWiseTotal[element] = 0;
    outletWiseGross[element] = 0;
    outletWiseDiscount[element] = 0;
    outletWiseGst[element] = 0;
    data.forEach(el => {
      if (el.outlet == element) {
        outletWiseTotal[element] += parseInt(el.amount);
        outletWiseGross[element] += parseInt(el.gross);
        outletWiseDiscount[element] += parseInt(el.discount);
        outletWiseGst[element] += parseInt(el.GST);
      }
    });
    grandTotal += outletWiseTotal[element]; //calculating totals for Total column
    grandGross += outletWiseGross[element];
    grandDiscount += outletWiseDiscount[element];
    grandGst += outletWiseGst[element];
  });

  thead.appendChild(headerRow);
  headerRow = document.createElement("tr");
  th = document.createElement("th");
  th.innerHTML = "";
  headerRow.appendChild(th);

  for (i = 0; i < outlets.length + 1; i++) {
    th = document.createElement("th");
    th.innerHTML = "Discount";
    th.classList.add("text-center");
    th.classList.add("discount");
    headerRow.appendChild(th);

    th = document.createElement("th");
    th.innerHTML = "GST";
    th.classList.add("text-center");
    th.classList.add("gst");
    headerRow.appendChild(th);

    th = document.createElement("th");
    th.innerHTML = "Net_Amount";
    th.classList.add("text-center");
    th.classList.add("netAmount"); //adding class to column Net Amount
    headerRow.appendChild(th);

    th = document.createElement("th");
    th.innerHTML = "Gross_Amount";
    th.classList.add("text-center");
    th.classList.add("grossAmount"); //adding class to column Gross Amount
    headerRow.appendChild(th);
  }

  headerRow.insertBefore(th, headerRow.children[1]);
  thead.appendChild(headerRow);
  table.appendChild(thead);

  headerRow = document.createElement("tr");
  td = document.createElement("th");
  td.innerHTML = "Total";
  td.classList.add("text-center");
  headerRow.appendChild(td);

  outlets.forEach(element => { // these are the table rows for each column
    td = document.createElement("th");
    td.innerHTML = outletWiseGross[element].toLocaleString('en-IN');
    td.classList.add("text-right");
    headerRow.appendChild(td);

    td = document.createElement("th");
    td.innerHTML = outletWiseDiscount[element].toLocaleString('en-IN');
    td.classList.add("text-right");
    headerRow.appendChild(td);

    td = document.createElement("th");
    td.innerHTML = outletWiseGst[element].toLocaleString('en-IN');
    td.classList.add("text-right");
    headerRow.appendChild(td);

    td = document.createElement("th");
    td.innerHTML = outletWiseTotal[element].toLocaleString('en-IN');
    td.classList.add("text-right");
    headerRow.appendChild(td);


  });
  td = document.createElement("th");
  td.innerHTML = grandTotal.toLocaleString('en-IN');
  td.classList.add("text-right");
  headerRow.insertBefore(td, headerRow.children[1]);

  td = document.createElement("th");
  td.innerHTML = grandGst.toLocaleString('en-IN');
  td.classList.add("text-right");
  headerRow.insertBefore(td, headerRow.children[1]);

  td = document.createElement("th");
  td.innerHTML = grandDiscount.toLocaleString('en-IN');
  td.classList.add("text-right");
  headerRow.insertBefore(td, headerRow.children[1]);

  td = document.createElement("th");
  td.innerHTML = grandGross.toLocaleString('en-IN');
  td.classList.add("text-right");
  headerRow.insertBefore(td, headerRow.children[1]);


  thead.appendChild(headerRow);
  table.appendChild(thead);

  let tbody = document.createElement("tbody");
  billdates.forEach(element => {
    let row = document.createElement("tr");
    td = document.createElement("td");
    td.innerHTML = element;
    row.appendChild(td);

    let total = 0;
    let totalGross = 0;
    let totalDiscount = 0;
    let totalGST = 0;
    outlets.forEach(outlet => {
      let ta = 0;
      let tg = 0;
      let tdi = 0;
      let tgst = 0;
      data.forEach(d => {
        if (d.billdate == element && d.outlet == outlet) {
          total += parseInt(d.amount);
          totalGross += parseInt(d.gross);
          totalDiscount += parseInt(d.discount);
          totalGST += parseInt(d.GST);
          ta = d.amount;
          tg = d.gross;
          tdi = d.discount;
          tgst = d.GST;
        }
      });

      td = document.createElement("td");
      td.innerHTML = tg.toLocaleString('en-IN');
      td.classList.add("text-right");
      row.appendChild(td);

      td = document.createElement("td");
      td.innerHTML = tdi.toLocaleString('en-IN');
      td.classList.add("text-right");
      row.appendChild(td);

      td = document.createElement("td");
      td.innerHTML = tgst.toLocaleString('en-IN');
      td.classList.add("text-right");
      row.appendChild(td);

      td = document.createElement("td");
      td.innerHTML = ta.toLocaleString('en-IN');
      td.classList.add("text-right");
      row.appendChild(td);




    });


    td = document.createElement("td");
    td.innerHTML = total.toLocaleString('en-IN');
    td.classList.add("text-right");
    row.insertBefore(td, row.children[1]);

    td = document.createElement("td");
    td.innerHTML = totalGST.toLocaleString('en-IN');
    td.classList.add("text-right");
    row.insertBefore(td, row.children[1]);

    td = document.createElement("td");
    td.innerHTML = totalDiscount.toLocaleString('en-IN');
    td.classList.add("text-right");
    row.insertBefore(td, row.children[1]);



    td = document.createElement("td");
    td.innerHTML = totalGross.toLocaleString('en-IN');
    td.classList.add("text-right");
    row.insertBefore(td, row.children[1]);


    tbody.appendChild(row);
  });

  table.appendChild(tbody);
  tbl.innerHTML = "";
  tbl.appendChild(table);
  table.classList.add("table");
  table.classList.add("table-striped");
  table.classList.add("table-bordered");
  table.classList.add("table-hover");
  var test = $(table).DataTable({
    "scrollX": true,
    "scrollY": "100px",
    "paging": false,
    "info": false,
    "ordering": false,
    "searching": false,
    fixedColumns: {
      leftColumns: 5
    }
  });

  $(".showHideColumn").on('click', function() {
    var tableColumn = test.column($(this).attr('data-columnindex'));
    tableColumn.visible(!tableColumn.visible());
  })
}
let formatedData = formatData(data);
renderTable(formatedData);
```

```css
div.dataTables_wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

table.table-bordered>thead>tr>th {
  border: 1px solid white;
  white-space: nowrap;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  font-family: Verdana;
  font-size: 9pt;
  padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
  background-color: black;
  font-weight: normal;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
}

table.table-bordered>tbody>tr>td {
  border: 1px solid rgba(29, 150, 178, 1);
  white-space: nowrap;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  font-family: Verdana;
  font-size: 8pt;
  background-color: gray;
  padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
  color: black;
}

.showHideColumn {
  cursor: pointer;
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdn.datatables.net/fixedcolumns/3.2.6/js/dataTables.fixedColumns.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.18/css/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdn.datatables.net/fixedcolumns/3.2.5/css/fixedColumns.bootstrap4.min.css">
<a class="showHideColumn" data-columnindex="0">Gross Amount</a> -
<a class="showHideColumn" data-columnindex="1">Discount</a> -
<a class="showHideColumn" data-columnindex="2">Gst</a> -
<a class="showHideColumn" data-columnindex="3">Net Amount</a>
<br>
<table id="dailySales" class="table table-responsive"></table>
```

**Edit/Update**

I am now doing it with data-tables but,as using `data-columnindex` but its only hiding the first  column data as i ahve `gros amount`,`Discount`,`Gst`,`Net Amount` these are common in each column except `billdate` , so what i am trying to do is when i click on `Net Amount`  all net amount columns should hide

I think this can be done using data-tables without changing my java-script
Anyone out here please help me out

Comment: You shouldn't modify a dataTable with jquery after creating it. Use dataTable's api and filters to handle data.

Comment: @Bogdan i have made this in my several reports now i have to do it this way only,any css mistake i am making?

Comment: If you got used to go from Mumbai to New Delhi via Kolkata doesn't mean anybody else can tell you the directions to go this route and it certainly doesn't mean there's no point of going *shorter* way one day.

Comment: CSS can't duplicate your columns, so there's definitely something wrong with your jQuery code

Comment: @user11299053 no i am not saying that i can't use data-tables but i have done some codes with jQuery that's why i am preferring that, can you give me example with my code using data-tables, because i have col-span inside my columns

Comment: @user11299053 if you can help me with data-table code then that can be helpful, i have posted what i have tried,i don't think down-voting is a good thing to do here sir

Comment: There's only about 10 lines of DataTable's code (out of undue 377) and you use just 'fixed column' and 'fixed header' out of its plethora of features. I'm guessing it is easier to emulate those **without** DataTables than force the latter to show expected behavior.

Comment: @user11299053 I am very new to data-tables that's why i was using jquery to achieve my requirements  if you can help me out then it will be very good for me

Comment: I have downvoted your question as it has very little to do with DataTables and your 377 lines of code (which is an absolute overkill, considering the task you solve) make it nearly impossible to guess where exactly you've gone wrong with this particular issue.

Comment: @user11299053 i am hiding and showing columns on click handler so it is easy to get that, any how i am commenting all the lines where i am doing what

Comment: The problem is that you are modifying a DataTable through jQuery instead of using DataTable API. DataTable plugin expects you to not touch its HTML code. You can reduce all your work, problems and lines of code by a lot just by using DataTable API.

Comment: @JorgeFuentesGonzález can you help me with some code as i have uploaded

Answer (score 4):

I think you need to hide column value. its two liner code. you can do it in two step.

1- Declare table variable globally.

```
var table;
```

now assign datatable object to it.

```
table =$(table).DataTable({ //adding datatabl functionality 
    "scrollX": true,
    "scrollY": $bodyHeight + "px",
    "scrollCollapse": true,
    "paging": false,
    "info": false,
    "ordering": false,
    "searching": false,
    fixedColumns: {
      leftColumns: 1
    }
  });
```

Now you have table object you can play with it.

```
$("#save").on("click", function() {

   // Get the column API object
    var column = table.column( $(this).attr('data-column') );
    // Toggle the visibility
    column.visible( ! column.visible() );
});
```

for more reference see [here](https://datatables.net/examples/api/show_hide.html).

Comment: That's what he is doing @dheerajkumar. Helping you with your code.

Comment: @JorgeFuentesGonzález i have updated my code, doing like this only but not getting the result please check once

Comment: The answer is to use DataTables API @dheerajkumar. As you can see, He uses `column.visible( ! column.visible() );` to toggle column visibility, instead of modifying the table HTML code. The code is much cleaner.

Comment: @JorgeFuentesGonzález my columns are col-span i have done something like this only as you can see my code snippet

Comment: @dheerajkumar Hmm... I still see you modifying `innerHTML` and appending childs and such to the table. With DataTables you never have to work directly with the DOM. There are so much things to work out here actually. I suggest you to recreate the script from zero, but only using DataTable API. Is worth it to read the documentation and learn what you can do with it. You will save a lot of development hours, error debugging and such.

Comment: @JorgeFuentesGonzález you are saying that i should remove my JS code and populate this table using Data-tables, no i can't do that as you can see JSON is not perfect so i am looping it to create my table, earlier i was using jquery to show hide the columns now i want to do that with Data-tables that's it, i don't thing i have to remove my JS code what i have done till now

Comment: See the key point is do whatever you are doing but once you push your data in to DataTable API, play with Datatable API instead of yours.

Comment: @dheerajkumar as Negi says, if your data is not formatted to your likings, then process it in JavaScript and create another object with the good format. Then you feed that object to the DataTable. That's a good practice as you let DataTable do the work. You just feed to it the data with the format that it wants. Is much easier to do it that way. What you are doing now has zero support from anyone (neither random freaks as us or even original DataSet developers) as it goes against any good practice in programming. Like people say in my country: "you are trying to kill a fly with a cannon".

Comment: I know that you've put a lot of effort in your code and lost a lot of time with it, but that's our everyday bread. If you got the wrong and hard way and there's a better way, go for it although you discard all your current work, as will make the future work easier. This is a really good example of that. Do not waste any line of code more and start again doing it the good way. Looking what you have and what you are trying to do, I assure you that this is a good advice.

Comment: @JorgeFuentesGonzález but this table structure also accepts data-tables very well, i am making mt table scroll vertically and horizontally